# How am i able to change interface variable value in a class which is implementing that interface

Tags: java

I have created one interface which looks like below:

```
public interface CalculatorInterface 
{ 
      int x=10; int y=15; int z=x+y; 
      public void add1();
}
```

Then i created one class which is implementing it. The class looks like below:

```
public class AdvClass2 implements CalculatorInterface {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       int x=50;
       System.out.println("X value is" +x);
    }

    @Override
    public void add1() {
        System.out.println("I am in Add Method");       
    }}
```

But the rule says i am not allowed to change interface variable value right. Can somebody tell me what am i doing wrong?

Comment: 1 use starting big letters

Comment: 2. im surprising is this lega? Do it compile? Interface cammot have "variables"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are actually changing the local variable in the `main` function. This variable is different from the one you declared in the interface which is indeed `public, static and final` by default. But there are no such restrictions on local variables.

Also if there is a variable with same name in the local scope then that variable is preferred over the variable with same name in the outer scope.

**Edit:**

As I explained earlier you are declaring `x` as local variable in main function and it is different from the variable `x` in the interface. In your main function do the following if you want a compile error while trying to change the interface `x` variable:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   x=50;
   System.out.println("X value is" +x);
}
```

Now you will see a compile error telling you the interface's x variable cannot be assigned.

Comment: But from the Java Documentation i saw that once any class is implementing any interface, any variable declared in the interface cannot be changed in class. I am surprised that i am able to compile successfully.

Comment: @Swarup as I explained the important thing to notice so that you understand `why you re not getting compile error` is that you are not changing the interface variable `x`. Instead you are creating a completely new local variable x using `int x = 50;` and thus, not getting any error. But remove `int` as I have done in the edited answer and you will see a compile error.

Comment: Thanks Yug for the clarity in your explanation

Comment: @Swarup could you mark one of the answers as accepted if your doubts are resolved? It will only help the community.

Answer (score 1):

Variables in interface are by default   **static final** ( you can call it as **static constant** ) variables ,so you can assign value to it only once  , it's value cant be changed afterwards.

check this site for final keyword - https://www.javatpoint.com/final-keyword

Answer (score 0):

Since an interface can not be instantiated directly, the interface variables are static and final by default. We are not allowed to change them.

Interfaces can't contain any implementation. A Java interface can only contain method signatures and fields.

I think you need a better design. So the interface should be like:

```
public interface ICalculator {

public int add1(int a, int b); // this is the method signature, not the implementation.

}
```

Then in the `AdvClass2` you can implement the `add1` method:

```
@Override
public int add1(int a, int b) {
   int result = a + b;

   return result;
}
```